# Ionic build not reflecting changes when running or deploying to app

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using the standard ionic template project that is generated from by WebStorm.

When I make simple changes (like adding a test alert(...)) in `app.run(...)` in `app.js` and run the following set of commands, the changes are not reflected when the app runs or is deployed to the phone.

The following commands are ran from the root of my project.

```
gulp
ionic build android
ionic run|emulate android
```

Is there something I am missing that would not reflect the changes I am making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to determine why this issue was occurring.

As I was testing on my android phone (Galaxy to be specific), everytime I would run the following command...

```
ionic run android
```

It would appear to deploy/install to my device, and it would open up the app. Howevever, it wasn't actually deploying the newest version as I was already running the previous version in the background.

The fix for this was to make sure that the application was not running (in foreground or background). This required me to make sure that if it was running, that I stop it before testing any changes.

Answer (score 8):

Recently experienced this issue. What helped me is removing the android platform:

```
ionic platform rm android
```

then, re-adding it.

```
ionic platform add android
```

make sure you delete the app from your device before running/installing again, then run:

```
ionic run android
```

hope this helps

Comment: When remove a platform use ionic cordova platfrom remove android  the way its done above will just rename it.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue after upgrading cordova and ionic to the latest versions.

> ionic info

[image]

Downgraded cordova and ionic versions to match my previous environment, it started taking the changes all over again.

commands:

> npm install -g cordova@6.2.0
>
> npm -d install -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.35

Everything works well with the following combination for me.
[image]

Hope this helps someone!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all files inside www folder and run ionic lab to update then, for some reason when I run cordova run android the version deployed was the old one, but when I remove the files in www folder the new version was deployed.